# Dynamically add panelGroup without refreshing entire parent

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to add h:panelGroup dynamically from backendBean but without refresh entire parent component.

Here is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="dialogs">
</h:panelGroup>
```

To this panelGroup I want to add other panelGroup from backendBean:

```
public void addPanelGroup() {
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    doFind(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "dialogs");
    HtmlPanelGroup div = new HtmlPanelGroup();
    div.setLayout("block");
    div.setId(id);
    found.getChildren().add(div);
}

private void doFind(FacesContext context, String clientId) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().invokeOnComponent(context, clientId, new ContextCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invokeContextCallback(FacesContext context,
                UIComponent component) {
            found = component;
        }
    });
}
```

If I call 
    `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("dialogs")`
at the end of addPanelGroup method it works. But when I add second panelGroup on `dialogs` I must refresh `dialogs` second time. Is there any way to add new panelGroup without refresh entire parent panelGroup?
Thanks for help.

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? I only see plain jsf code

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, it's plain jsf, but I use PrimeFaces library on my project too. I did not mention it, sorry.

Comment: 'Using' it is not a reason to tag the question with it. You use java to and html and css and electricity ;-)